# Calculate The object angle(face) having two points?

Tags: c++, math, geometry, angle

C++, I want calculate the angle of the direction of the two points.

Here is a picture which shows the two points and the direction of how to get the angle of the direction?

[image]

p1 - start point. p2 - direction point. me need direction angle(facing?) from p1 to p2

Comment: [Πυθαγόρας](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity)?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2GX0MUw.png?1

Comment: Well, so what?? It's still veeery basic geometrical math, you have all the necessary functions at hand in c++ ([`#include <cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath)), and my link explains well, what to do. (You should note the c++ functions use radian angle values as arguments, rather than degrees).

Comment: p1 - start point. p2 - direction point. me need direction angle from p1 to p2

Comment: Please show the code you actuallly have tried, and clearly state why it fails.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, I tried to use: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30898572/edit but the code returns the 0-2, but I need from 0 to 360.

Comment: Convert degrees to radians (2π == 360°) , and back.

Comment: How to convert it into direction(from start point to end point)? (0-360) ?

Comment: I just told you radian value [2 * π equivalents to 360° in degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees)s, what's actually so hard about converting the one into the other and back? Do yourself a favor and buy a college primer math book dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>

// ...
double angle = atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
// ...
```

If you want to, you can also make sure that `p1 != p2`, because if it is then you'll get a domain error.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2GX0MUw.png ??

Comment: @ZeroMemory In your image, that angle is always 90 degrees. That's the definition of a right angle.

Comment: Your function does not return 0-360.

Comment: StartXY: -4080.929199 , -5206.329102 . NextXY: -4029.881348 , -5174.799805 . EndXY: -1141.065918 , -4052.538818 . Angle12: 0.553291

Comment: p1 - start point. p2 - direction point. me need direction angle from p1 to p2

Comment: How to convert into angle? (0-360) ?

Comment: @ZeroMemory [_"How to convert into angle? (0-360) ?"_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898515/calculate-the-object-angleface-having-two-points#comment49837839_30898515)